# How destroy a service explicitly in dotcloud?

Tags: dotcloud

After removed a mondodb services from dotcloud.yml and push to dotcloud I have this warning:

```
Warning: Service mongo is no longer in your dotcloud.yml, but will continue running until you destroy it explictly.
```

But in the CLI documentation or in the dotcloud page I don't fine how destroy explicitly a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `destroy` command, where you specify the application and service that you want to destroy.

If you just put the application you will destroy the whole application, so be careful and make sure you specify the service you want to destroy.

Here is an example.

*Check your dotcloud cli version to know which version to use.*

```
$ dotcloud --version
```

**CLI version 0.9.x**

```
# destroy the application
$ dotcloud destroy --application <app name>

# destroy a service in the application
$ dotcloud destroy --application <app name> <service name>
```

See these docs for more info:  http://docs.dotcloud.com/firststeps/in-depth/#deleting-services

**CLI versions 0.4.x**

```
# destroy the application
$ dotcloud destroy <app_name>

# destroy a service in the application
$ dotcloud destroy <app_name>.<service_name>
```

See these docs for more info: http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/firststeps/in-depth/#deleting-services

**Note**: You can also use the dashboard. But, it looks like you can only destroy the application, and it doesn't let you destroy the service. So that won't do you much good right now, but it might get added in the future.

Comment: thanks!!! in the CLI help just say `destroy Destroy an existing app` don't say nothing about destroy a service